# Request for self-study reference

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

I have a very basic knowledge of Lie groups, and want to know more/study about homogeneous spaces (in particular, the kinds of functional analysis done on abstract homogeneous spaces). Could anyone please suggest a couple of good books where I should start?

(I Googled, but not sure how to choose). Thank you in advance!